# A geometric quantity associated to a vector field on a surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Let  $(M, g)$  be  a  $2$  dimensional  Riemannian  manifold.

Then  we  consider  the    Riemannian  metric on TM [described  here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52509/riemannian-metric-of-the-tangent-bundle).

Assume  that  $X:M\to  TM$  is  a  vector  field.  For  every  $p\in M, \quad DX_p(T_pM)$   is  a 2  dimensional  subspace  of  the  tangent  space of $TM$ at point  $(p,X(p))$.  We define the  function $q:M \to  \mathbb{R}$ with $$q(p)=\kappa(DX_p(T_pM))$$
where  $\kappa $  is the sectional  curvature.

To  what  extend does the function $q$ and  its integral $\int_M q\; d\Omega_g$ have  some    information about the  dynamics  of  $X$?  Under what  kind of  perturbations of  $X$,  this  integral is  stable(unchanged)?

Comment: Is $D$ the Levi-Civita connection? Then isn't $DX_p(T_pM)$ simply a subspace of $T_pM$ (i.e. the covariant derivative of the vector field at $p$ is a tangent vector at $p$)? I also don't see why the subspace should be two-dimensional, e.g. if $X=0$, then the subspace is zero-dimensional. Am I missing something?

Comment: $D$ denotes the derivative of the map $X$. The Levi Civita connection is needed to get a Riemannian metric on TM.

Comment: @S.Surace  D is the derivative as  it

Comment: as @Sebastian said.

Comment: If the vector field is identically zero then q should be the Gaussian curvature, I think

Comment: @MartindeBorbon  yes thank you. I think so since M  is embedded in $TM$ isometrically.